# apache in container does not start with NFS directory

Tags: linux, docker, apache, containers, nfs

I have a problem that and need your help with.

Following the scenario:

I have WEB applications in docker, which have a proxy (reverse) in apache, it directs to the other containers that are in the WEB application (also in apache)
These applications are all on port 443, that is, they all have certificates.

The certificates are in a filesystem and I mount the directory through NFS.

These machines are from an approval environment, so they are only connected during business hours.

Here we have the problem.

The apache (proxy) does not go up and with that the application does not stay in the air. I found that it does not go up because apache only goes up when it finds the directory with the certificates. Because when the docker is going up it still hasn't finished mounting the NFS directory

mount is outside the container, on the docker host. It is mounted via /etc/fstab: server:/certificates/certs/ /apps/sgugpl/certificates nfs defaults 0 0 ## CERTIFICATES ##

And in docker-compose.yml - ${VOLUMES_PATH}/certificates:/etc/httpd/conf.d/certificates

I made some changes to the directory: /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service apps-sgugpl-certificates.mount
Wants=network-online.target apps-sgugpl-certificates.mount

I accessed the directory through the container shell and it showed the contents of the share.

I ran ls -l and the permissions appear: lrwxrwxrwx - symbolic link / -rw-r--r-- - certificate when accessing the file with cat, it reads the file normally –

I added at the end of these lines apps-sgugpl-certificados.mount But it didn't work either. –

In short:

I need to know if there is any way for docker to go up after the mounted directory?

I do not know if i was clear. But thanks in advance for help.

If I use the docker-compose down and up command, after starting the machine, apache manages to stay UP.

If I remove the nfs share, and put the certificate in a local directory, it starts normally.

But it's not my ideal scenario.

Comment: Details, please. NFS mounted on the host and shared with `-v`? Mounted directly during container bringup with `--mount`? Something else? Please don't make us guess at what steps need to be taken to reproduce the problem ourselves; in an ideal world the question would provide a proper [mre], steps someone else can follow exactly as given to see the problem themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new around here.

mount is outside the container, on the docker host. It is mounted via /etc/fstab:

server:/certificates/certs/ /apps/sgugpl/certificates nfs defaults 0 0 ## CERTIFICATES ##

And in docker-compose.yml
  - ${VOLUMES_PATH}/certificates:/etc/httpd/conf.d/certificates

Comment: continue
I made some changes to the directory:

/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service apps-sgugpl-certificates.mount
Wants=network-online.target apps-sgugpl-certificates.mount

I added at the end of these lines apps-sgugpl-certificados.mount

But it didn't work either.

Comment: If you get a shell inside the container, are the files from the bind mount _not there at all_, or do they have the wrong permissions (so they're there but you can't read them)?

Comment: BTW, please feel encouraged to [edit] the question instead of only adding clarifications in comments; the goal is for the question itself to be complete enough that someone can write an answer based only off its text (without needing to read comments / follow links / view screenshots / etc).

Comment: Answering your question from the other comment:

Yes, I accessed the directory through the container shell and it showed the contents of the share.

Comment: Okay, if the files show up -- do you get a permission error when you try to actually read them? What are the permission and ownership as shown by `stat` or `ls -l`?

Comment: I ran ls -l and the permissions appear:

lrwxrwxrwx - symbolic link / -rw-r--r-- - certificate

when accessing the file with cat, it reads the file normally

Comment: I'd like to have a bit more clarity on what "didn't work" means. Do you get an error that identifies a specific syscall that failed? If not, can you find such an error by digging around with `strace`?